# What field type would you use to show when a post is published (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I am building a blogging application and I want to be able to set when a post is published. For example, I want to have a field in my "edit post" page that gives me a drop down menu for date, month, year, and time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right field type is `datetime`.

One option in forms is [datetime_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select).

If you use jquery ui, there is a plugin [datetime_picker](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) might be what you're looking for?